# How is associated data stored when pushing and popping register contents

Tags: assembly, x86

How does the CPU know what value to put back into a register when `POP` is called?

If e.g. we `PUSH ECX`, call some procedure which modifies the content of `ECX` and then call `POP ECX`, how is the original value that was in `ECX` linked between the `push` and `pop` instructions?

Are there additional instructions generated automatically to store this value and tie it to an instruction?

Comment: push and pop are separate instructions.  They just store or load and modify ESP.  Look them up in the insn set ref: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/.  They do nothing more and nothing less than what you see in the "Operation" section.

Comment: It uses an area of memory as stack. So `push` just writes to memory, and `pop` reads it back. The only link is the stack pointer and that you `pop` into the same place. `push eax; pop ecx` is legal and will of course set `ecx` to `eax`. `push eax` is basically equivalent to: `lea esp, [esp-4]; mov [esp], eax`

Comment: Ah, so pop just pops whatever is on the top of the stack into the destination?

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much the definition of pop :)

Comment: What confused me was when procedures are called in between those instructions, e.g if the stack is not cleaned up and that procedure also modifies the contents, but yeah, those are different issues :)

Comment: The stack must be "cleaned up" or otherwise be in a known state for `PUSH` and `POP` to be used effectively. There is a specific responsibility assigned to the maintenance of `esp/rsp` (the stack register) in every ABI. If some function violates that, then you have _stack corruption_ and all bets are off (just like heap corruption, etc).

Answer (score 3):

[PUSH](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html) and [POP](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POP.html) are pretty simple instructions.  They just store or load and modify ESP.

You can POP something that was written with a different store instruction, and vice versa.

They do nothing more and nothing less than what you see in the "Operation" section (see those links for HTML extracts of Intel's instruction set reference, which is what you should look at any time you want to know what an instruction does).  See [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) for a mostly-complete index, and the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links.

It's up to you to make sure nothing overwrites the stack memory where you pushed something you want to retrieve later.  Note that functions are allowed to modify their args on the stack, so you need to redo the stores of args to call the same function again with the same args (unless you wrote the function and can guarantee that it doesn't clobber that memory).

---

> Are there additional instructions generated automatically

Standard x86 asm syntax doesn't have any pseudo-instructions that assemble to multiple machine instructions.

Typical RISC systems make it easy to generate the pair of instructions necessary to put an arbitrary 32-bit constant in a register.  MIPS asm syntax even has pseudo-instructions that implicitly use a register!

Instead, x86's CISC design makes the hardware deal with all that complexity.  You can put a 64-bit constant into a register with a 10-byte `mov rcx, 0x123456789ABCD`.

Answer (score 1):

Push and pop are just ways to access the stack, so understanding a stack is the key here.  The stack is simply RAM.  For global variables, for example, there is one memory location in RAM (for sake of argument) dedicated to that variable.  So when you access (the RAM version of) the variable, you are reading and writing a fixed address.  But with a local variable (for languages that support recursion), for each instance of that function you need a new copy of that variable. To make ten calls recursively, you need ten memory locations to store the ten copies of that variable.  A stack makes this trivial.  You can think of it as allocating and freeing memory, like `malloc()` and `free()`, but very simplified.

Push and pop are like doing the following in C:

```
sp--;
*sp = x;
x = *sp; sp++;
```

The CPU knows nothing nor cares nothing about preserving your original value.  You, the programmer (indirectly through the compiler), ask for things to be done, and in the case of using the stack to preserve a register value, the compiler or you directly if you use assembly language will use a push to "save a value on the stack", and pop to "restore a value from the stack".

It is up to the programmer or compiler to make sure that the push and pops and other modifications to the stack pointer insure that the `push ecx` and `pop ecx` are operating on the same ram address.  If that is done then "how the CPU knows" is `ecx` was written to address X with the push, and at some point later address X is read and the value is placed in `ecx`. With a global variable, the address M for that variable is a fixed address for the life of the program. If that variable's contents needs to be in a register for some reason, it is read from M and then put back to M.  But when using the stack, you can have quick-and-dirty allocation of memory for some period of time—say a function—enter the function and if you want 32 bytes then you simply `sp = sp-32`, and  you have now just allocated 32 bytes.  You could then save `ecx` "on the stack" either with a push (allocating 4 more bytes) or save it at some address say `sp+8`.  Then, before leaving the function, you could read `sp+8` and put that value back in `ecx`.  `sp+8` is the address X where `ecx` was saved.

You could instead, when entering the function or really at any time, `push ecx`, allocating 4 bytes and writing `ecx` to that address, X. If you then `push edx`, it would be at address X-4.  Later (if you keep your stack pointer accesses paired up correctly), when you `pop edx` it will come from address X-4, and then the `pop ecx` from X.  So what was written to address X—your original value of `ecx`—is now read back and `ecx` is returned to its original value.